# Custom loss function with multiple targets

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm training a model and I'm using a custom loss function. I have been using a single target but now I want to try to feed two targets.

My custom loss function looks like this

```
def CCC(y_true, y_pred):
  import keras.backend as K 
  
  s_xy = K.mean( (y_true - K.mean(y_true)) * (y_pred - K.mean(y_pred)) )
    
  x_m = K.mean(y_true)
  y_m = K.mean(y_pred)
  
  s_x_sq = K.var(y_true)
  s_y_sq = K.var(y_pred)
    
  ccc = (2.0*s_xy) / (s_x_sq + s_y_sq + (x_m-y_m)**2)
    
  return 1 - ccc
```

With one target, `y_true` and `y_pred` are 1-d lists and the function can correctly execute operations such `sum`, `mean` etc.

My question is: if I use two targets like `[target1, target2]`, what is the shape of `y_true` and `y_preds` going to be? Are they going to be 2-d lists and will I have to split them and execute the operations on each list?

Answer (score 0):

The model with multiple outputs can be compiled as the following code.

```
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr)
losses = {
  "target1": CCC,
  "target2": Some loss...,
  "target3": Some loss...}

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=losses,metrics=["accuracy"])
```

The data is fed to the model at training by a dictionary, and the output and preiction of the model is also in a form of a dictionary not a list.

```
train_y={'target1':label1,'target2':label2,'target3':label3}
model.fit(x=train_x,y=train_y,epochs=10,...)
```

The target names `target1, target2, target3` must match the name of the layer in the model.